# oracle sql query to combine field percentages

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table such as this

```
NAME   CATEGORY    PERCENT
Black  Color       0.10
Blue   Color       0.30
Green  Color       0.60
Fast   Speed       0.40
Slow   Speed       0.60
```

What I want the output to be is

```
COMBINEDCAT   COMBINEDPC
BlackFast      0.04
BlackSlow      0.06
BlueFast       0.12
BlueSlow       0.18
GreenFast      0.24
GreenSlow      0.36
```

So essentially I'm looking for a way to multiply the names against eachother to form all possible category outcomes, does this make any sense? I've been struggling with this for some time, any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

EDIT: There could be limitless categories, so I'm looking for something that would not need to reference each category in the query.

Comment: So if you added a category "Species" that is "Cat" or "Dog", you'd like something like BlackFastCat/BlackFastDog/BlackSlowCat/BlackSlowDog/... automatically? Is that what you mean by the edit?

Comment: hi Joachim that's correct it would keep appending to the combinedcat

Comment: How do you know the order of the categories? Why "BlackFast" and not "FastBlack"?

Answer (score 4):

```
select t1.Name || t2.Name as CombinedCat,
       t1.Percent * t2.Percent as CombinedPc
  from your_table t1
  join your_table t2
    on t2.Category = 'Speed'
 where t1.Category = 'Color'
 order by CombinedCat
```

**EDIT: Adjustment in the problem description**

If you're looking to do this with a dynamic amount of categories, you can do it with the following query, which uses a recursive CTE:

```
with Categories as (
  select category,
         row_number() over (order by category) as seq
    from your_table
   group by category),
RecursiveCTE (Name, Percent, seq) as (
  select t.Name,
         t.Percent,
         c.seq
    from your_table t
    join Categories c
      on c.category = t.category
     and c.seq = 1
   union all   
  select r.Name || t.Name as Name,
         r.Percent * t.Percent as Percent,
         c.seq
    from RecursiveCTE r
    join Categories c
      on c.seq = r.seq + 1
    join your_table t
      on t.category = c.category
)
select t.Name as CombinedCat,
       Percent as CombinedPc
  from RecursiveCTE t
 where t.seq = (select max(seq) from Categories)
order by t.Name
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/509cf/1)

The query above concatenates the category names alphabetically, but you can adjust that by changing the `order by` clause in the `row_number()` function in the `Categories` CTE:

```
row_number() over (order by category) as seq
```

Comment: I think that might do better as a cross join, with the predicate on speed in the where clause.

Comment: I added a new query that should be able to deal with a dynamic number of categories. Don't know how well it will perform on large amounts of data though.

Answer (score 1):

What about this.

- You join with all other categories `"<>"` than you.
- But only join with the ones "bigger" than you to avoid invert duplicates.

.

```
   SELECT 
       T1."CATEGORY", 
       T2."CATEGORY", 
       T1."NAME"||T2."NAME" as  "COMBINEDCAT", 
       T1."PERCENT"*T2."PERCENT" as "COMBINEDPC"
   FROM Table1 T1
   INNER JOIN Table1 T2
      ON T1."CATEGORY" < T2."CATEGORY"
   ORDER BY T1."CATEGORY", T2."CATEGORY", T1."NAME"||T2."NAME"
```

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fe3196/1)**

I include the categories on the select so you can validate the joins, also include a new category `COST`

**OUTPUT**

```
| CATEGORY | CATEGORY | COMBINEDCAT | COMBINEDPC |
|----------|----------|-------------|------------|
|    Color |     Cost |  BlackCheap |       0.03 |
|    Color |     Cost |   BlackHigh |       0.04 |
|    Color |     Cost |    BlackLow |       0.03 |
|    Color |     Cost |   BlueCheap |       0.09 |
|    Color |     Cost |    BlueHigh |       0.12 |
|    Color |     Cost |     BlueLow |       0.09 |
|    Color |     Cost |  GreenCheap |       0.18 |
|    Color |     Cost |   GreenHigh |       0.24 |
|    Color |     Cost |    GreenLow |       0.18 |
|    Color |    Speed |   BlackFast |       0.04 |
|    Color |    Speed |   BlackSlow |       0.06 |
|    Color |    Speed |    BlueFast |       0.12 |
|    Color |    Speed |    BlueSlow |       0.18 |
|    Color |    Speed |   GreenFast |       0.24 |
|    Color |    Speed |   GreenSlow |       0.36 |
|     Cost |    Speed |   CheapFast |       0.12 |
|     Cost |    Speed |   CheapSlow |       0.18 |
|     Cost |    Speed |    HighFast |       0.16 |
|     Cost |    Speed |    HighSlow |       0.24 |
|     Cost |    Speed |     LowFast |       0.12 |
|     Cost |    Speed |     LowSlow |       0.18 |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `cross join` to get the desired result.

[Fiddle with sample data](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/12071/1)

```
select 
n.name||s.name as combinedcat,
n.percent*s.percent
from (select distinct name, percent from tablename where category = 'Color') n
cross join (select distinct name, percent from tablename where category = 'Speed') s
```

Comment: this would have potentially unlimited category's, I need something that would be able to dynamically reference the category from the original table